# Matching values for reaped Key value in R

Tags: r, match, vlookup

I have to two tables,T1 and T2 containing data, with unique key "Month".
Final Table is the required output.
I am getting output in T2 while using below code, is there any way to get same output.

```
Final Table$Value <- T1$Value[match(Final Table$Month, T1$Month)]
```

```html
T1   T2   Final Table 
Month Value  Month Value  Month Value
Dec-15 110.655  Dec-15 86.915  Dec-15 110.655
Dec-15 78.255  Dec-15 86.915  Dec-15 78.255
Dec-15 86.915  Dec-15 86.915  Dec-15 86.915
Jan-16 83.141  Dec-15 86.915  Dec-15 110.655
Jan-16 66.341  Dec-15 86.915  Dec-15 78.255
Jan-16 71.399  Dec-15 86.915  Dec-15 86.915
Feb-16 66.599  Jan-16 71.399  Jan-16 83.141
Feb-16 80.741  Jan-16 71.399  Jan-16 66.341
Feb-16 71.312  Jan-16 71.399  Jan-16 71.399
   Jan-16 71.399  Jan-16 83.141
   Jan-16 71.399  Jan-16 66.341
   Jan-16 71.399  Jan-16 71.399
   Feb-16 71.312  Feb-16 66.599
   Feb-16 71.312  Feb-16 80.741
   Feb-16 71.312  Feb-16 71.312
   Feb-16 71.312  Feb-16 66.599
   Feb-16 71.312  Feb-16 80.741
   Feb-16 71.312  Feb-16 71.312
```

Comment: You may check `?merge` `left_join` etc in dplyr.  The issue is in uniquely identifying the 'Value' from the 'Month' as there are different values for each 'Month'

Comment: can you specify what kind of join do you want ? do you want all the rows in T1 even if there are no matching values in T2 ? how about the opposite?

Comment: Actually I need values in T2 which has only Months as a key.

Answer (score 0):

Some how I could to that using below trick:

```
T1 <- rbind(as.data.frame.array(T1,T1))

Final Table$Value <- T1$Value[match(Final Table$Month,T1$Month)]
```